# Can i use a full node data to fork a new chain using ganache-cli

Tags: ganache-cli

I am trying to use the forking feature of ganache-cli to get a dry-run version of an EVM-compatible blockchain. my issue is that after a while of running `ganache-cli` with the `--fork` option, all transactions start to timeout as, in my opinion, ganache loses contact with the original blockchain RPC endpoint that I used when launching. this is a major issue I am facing and my only reasonable fix is to download or synchronize a node locally and use the chain data from that node as a basis for my new ganache-based test system, of course with the added accounts.

Is there a way to do that, I can't seem to find how to do that in the official docs or on github.

Comment: It should work if you enable http server with `--http` in the geth command line.

Comment: @Ismael --http is just a way to create a HTTP server, it has nothing to do with forking the main chain.

Comment: The ganache's fork option requires an RPC endpoint, it can be provided by a geth instance running with http enabled.